# How can I filter a row by multiple conditions?

Tags: r

If my data look like this for example:

```
data <- tibble(NR. = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
               value = c(NA,NA,4,0,0,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0))
```

How can I filter that I receive the NR. where the corresponding values have both a 0 & NA (so NR. 2 and 4, NR. 1 has no 0 and NR. 3 has no NA)

Answer (score 0):

Like so? You can use `semi_join()` to retrieve the original (non-collapsed) rows, but filtered.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define data
data <- tibble(NR. = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
               value = c(NA,NA,4,0,0,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0))

# define predicate function for condition
has_zero_and_na <- function(x) {
  any(is.na(x)) & any(x == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# filter data
data |> 
  summarise(has_zero_and_na(value),
            .by = NR.) |> 
  filter(`has_zero_and_na(value)`)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>     NR. `has_zero_and_na(value)`
#>   <dbl> <lgl>                   
#> 1     2 TRUE                    
#> 2     4 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using `all` where you ensure that both 0 and NA are contained within `value` for each `NR.`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data |>
  filter(all(c(0, NA) %in% value), .by = NR.)
```

**Output**

```
    NR. value
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     0
2     2     0
3     2    NA
4     4    NA
5     4    NA
6     4     0
```